# Stripping a URL of an ID to Query MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

if i have a category page that im rendering by querying the subcategories in my database, then if i click on one of the subcategories it sends me to

```
mydomain.com/product_list.php?id=subcategory.
```

is there a way take the subcategory from the url to query the database to only show the products in that subcategory?

i think it'll look something like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you read? What research have you done? This is fairly basic and can be stripped down into much smaller individual tasks that are covered in any decent book on those technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be obtained from [`$_GET` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

```
$subcategory_id = $_GET['id'];
```

So this would become:

```
 if(array_key_exists('id', $_GET) and is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
     $subcategory_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
     $SQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE subcategory_id = $subcategory_id";
 }
```

Note I have cast the input variable to an integer to prevent SQL injection etc. As the ID must always be a number.

If you need to pass in a string then use [`mysql_real_escape_string()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on it first and don't type cast to an integer `(int)`:

```
 if(array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) {
     $subcategory_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
     $SQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Of course, that's assuming the table  name is `products`, and the ID columns is `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing.  I think to start some tutorials on PHP should be looked at, and the different types of http requests.

What you are looking at is called a GET request.  You can access all key, value pairs after the ? in a url through the superglobal `$_GET` this is an associate array containing all key => values.

So as per above `$_GET['id']` is the value you want.  But please before you begin look at SQL injection,  it is too easy to think that that value can be used directly to make a query.

Comment: thanks for the help, much appreciated :D im just learning, doing everything at once! i need to look more at the fundamentals of everything!